# Everytime I leave Minecraft when I go back-my inventory is gone, and I am in a different place. Everything I did (ex. start a garden.) is saved

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've only seen this in survival mode, so I don't know if it is an issue in creative. But it gets really annoying especially when I can't remember what was in my inventory. I have a resource pack and just one mod.

Comment: Turn off the mods.  Does it still happen?  No?  Then it's the mod.

Comment: Have you bought the game, and do you use official client? If you got some pirated version, it might allocate you random player names and then you have always new character. You should not play pirated game, as it is not only dangerous for viruses, also it is technically unstable.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a lot of information (or what mod you're using), so I think it's likely one of three things:

1. It's a server mod that is causing this. If you're running the game (or if it's single player) disable mods and see if that resolves the issue.
2. You're getting killed when you logout -- is the server you're playing on keep people around after they logout?
3. Someone is hacking you, or logging in as you, getting you killed, and then quitting the game. Try changing your password and see if that resolves the issue. (I've seen this happen a lot when my kids used to share an account before they each got their own.)

Comment: 4. Pirated client that generates random username at launch, thus having different character every time he loaded the game. But worldsave stays.

Comment: Good point, another option.